# method overloading C# having the largest number needs to be displayed

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

Here is the lab:

Important Note: To earn full credit, your solution must use overloading rather than optional parameters.

Create a method that takes two numbers as parameters and returns the larger of the two numbers. Overload the method so that it can also be called by passing three or four numbers. Write a Main() method that demonstrates each of the methods.

For example when i use these numbers:

1   3   5   7  =  should be 7 but it was  7

1   3   7   5  =  should be 7 but it was  7

1   7   3   5  =  should be 7 but it was  5

7   1   3   5  =  should be 7 but it was  5

I am still new to programing and C# is my first language so any help would be great.

```
        int firstNum = 7;
        int secondNum = 1;
        int thirdNum = 3;
        int fourthNum = 5;

        Console.WriteLine(LgNum(firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum, fourthNum));

        Console.Write("\nPress enter...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int LgNum(int num1, int num2)
    {
        if (num1 < num2)
        {
            return num2;
        }
        else if (num1 > num2)
        {
            return num1;
        }

        return  num1;

    }

    public static int LgNum(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        int firstLgNum; 

        firstLgNum = LgNum(num1, num2);

        return LgNum(firstLgNum, num3);
    }

    public static int LgNum(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4)
    {
        int secondLgNum;

        secondLgNum = LgNum(num3, num4);

        return LgNum(secondLgNum, num3, num4);
    }
```

Comment: Debug your code, step through and find out where it's going wrong. Your overload taking four parameters doesn't ever use `num1` or `num2`. Its implementation should probably be `return LgNum(LgNum(num1, num2), LgNum(num3, num4));`

Comment: Rob I feel pretty stupid now that i did not see it after looking at it for a very long time. Be most of all thanks for being kind and now chewing me up and spitting me back out.

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a really good guide for [Debugging small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) which I'd recommend you read.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
public static int LgNumber(int[] numbers)
{
    return numbers.Max();
}
```

but i guess its not allowed..?

You can still use an array an its .Max() function like this:

```
public static int LgNumber(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[]
                    {
                        num1,
                        num2,
                        num3,
                        num4
                    };

    return numbers.Max();
}
```

Comment: Also an array??

Comment: Definately not the ready functions, because purpose is to test the core logic!